# Convert a string into unicode escape sequences

Tags: python, string, unicode, escaping

How can I convert a string so that each character is replaced with the corresponding Unicode escape sequence?

Something like:

```py
def unicode_escape(s):
    """How do I write this?"""

print(unicode_escape("Hello, World!\n"))
# should print \u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F\u002C\u0020...
```

Comment: Use later where? Why do you need this rather than, for example, a UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Call `ord()` on each character, then format it as a 4-digit hex number preceded by the raw string `\u`

Comment: I am trying to make a tool (to learn even more python) that can sorta obfuscate python code, and this could make the code harder to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ord()` function returns the Unicode code point of a character. Just format this as `\u` followed by a 4-digit hex representation of that.

```
def unicode_escape(s):
    return "".join(map(lambda c: rf"\u{ord(c):04x}", s))
print(unicode_escape("Hello, World!\n"))
# prints \u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u002c\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064\u0021\u000a
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def encode(s):
    ret = []
    for c in s:
        n = ord(c)
        ret.append("\\u{:04x}".format(n))
    return "".join(ret)
#


print(encode("aeiouäöüßéá€æÆΑαΒβΓγ"))
```

Comment: `a` should be `\u0041`

Comment: Look at the example in the question, they want the hex escape even for ordinary letters.

Comment: Then it's even more trivial - and does not make much sense :-)

Comment: he explained that he wants to obfuscate it, so they shouldn't be able to read words like "Hello".

Answer (score 0):

The two existing answers are not entirely wrong, but they won't work with characters from 0x10000 to 0x10FFFF; `\u10000`, for instance, would be parsed as `\u1000` followed by a `0` in a string literal.

A conditional check should be added accordingly; depending on personal taste, you might also want to make it so that 0xFF and lower use `\x` instead of `\u`:

```py
def convert_to_unicode_escape_sequence(char: str) -> str:
  char_code = ord(char)

  if char_code <= 0xFF:
    return fr'\x{char_code:02x}'

  if char_code <= 0xFFFF:
    return fr'\u{char_code:04x}'
  
  return fr'\U{char_code:08x}'
```

```py
convert_to_unicode_escape_sequence('\x00')        # '\\x00'
convert_to_unicode_escape_sequence('\x61')        # '\\x61'
convert_to_unicode_escape_sequence('\u0100')      # '\\u0100'
convert_to_unicode_escape_sequence('\U00010000')  # '\\U0001000'
```

Alternatively, [`ascii()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii) might come in handy:

```py
ascii('\x00')        # "'\\x00'"
ascii('\u0100')      # "'\\u0100'"
ascii('\U00010000')  # "'\\x00'"
```

The value returned is a string containing two single quotes, one backslash, one `x`/`u`/`U` and the corresponding hex digits. Note that `ascii()` does not convert characters from 0x20 (SPACE) to 0x7E (TILDE):

```py
ascii('a')  # "'a'"
```

This is somewhat irrelevant, but backslash (0x5C) gets special treatment:

```py
ascii('\\')  # "'\\\\'"
```

With that in mind, the new implementation would look something like this:

```py
def convert_to_unicode_escape_sequence(char):
  if ' ' <= char <= '~':
    return fr'\x{char_code:02x}'

  return ascii(char)[1:-1]                # Strip the quotes
```

Alternatively:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

def convert_to_unicode_escape_sequence(char):
  # ascii('\x00')                     -> "'\\x00'"  (6 characters)
  # f'r{ascii('\x00')}'               -> "r'\\x00'" (7 characters)
  # literal_eval(f'r{ascii('\x00')}') -> '\\x00'    (4 characters)

  return literal_eval(f"r{ascii(char)}")
```

Still, this looks pretty much like a hack.